# Lib directory on 64-bit OpenSuse distribution

Tags: 64-bit, autotools, opensuse

A project I'm working on uses a non-standard distribution system, which internally downloads and compiles the dependency libraries. This crock launches, for each library, the `configure` script giving as prefix an internal directory of the compiling system. Then it runs `make` and `make install`, then it verifies the content by searching the install directory with the `lib/<mylib>.a` file. This last step fails.

Trying to understand what's happening, I compiled a pair of random libraries by myself, including one I'm the author of. I noticed that under my distribution (openSUSE, 64 bit) the installing path is not populated with `/lib`, but with `/lib64` instead.

It's clear that this is a setting of the distribution, and I'm pretty sure that this setting concerns a configuration of *autotools* shipped with the distro.

Is there a way of changing this behavior or, as an alternative, to read this information from the system (so that I can patch the above mentioned crock)?

Thanks for your help

**Update:** I learnt about the `--libdir` flag in `configure`, so I think I can solve my problem. Still I would like to know if there's a way of knowing this detail from somehow querying the distribution (e.g. read some configuration file).

Comment: This has nothing to do with autoconf on the system, since you are not running autoconf.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I'm not, but I'm running the `configure` script. My guess is that the `configure` based compile system can read some configuration from the operating system (e.g. some file in `/etc/`) in order to determine where the OS is expected to find the libraries.

Comment: If the configure script is looking in /etc/, that is a bug in the package.  I've never seen the behavior you are describing.  It may be that you are generating configure scripts with a patched version of autoconf.  Does the configure script contain the line "libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'" ?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I don't know if the configure script is looking in `/etc/`: it was just a way of saying that this is a system-dependent behavior. A patched version of autoconf is more likely, since the behavior is not concerning a single configure script, but basically every library that I compile manually.

Comment: Is libdir being assigned in /usr/local/share/config.site, or in a $CONFIG_SITE?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: BINGO! That's exactly what I was searching for. Please answer to the question, I'll be happy to accept your answer! Thanks to your answer I've found http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/autoconf/autoconf_138.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configure script should never try to make assumptions about the machine, or attempt to install libraries in locations other than ${exec_prefix}/lib unless the user explicitly requests a different location for $libdir.  One mechanism by which the user can explicitly request an alternate location is through a config.site file.  If the file ${prefix}/share/config.site exists, it may specify an alternate value for $libdir, causing the user to unknowingly explicitly specify an alternate installation location.

Answer (score 4):

That's a good answer by William Pursell.  I just wanted to add, since this question specifically concerns openSUSE, that openSUSE doesn't install a file called `config.site`.  The equivalent file is actually installed into `/usr/share/site` via the `site-config` rpm, and then activated via `/etc/profile/site.{c,}sh` which exports the `CONFIG_SITE` environment variable to point to this file.  That variable is then [honoured by autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Site-Defaults.html#Site-Defaults), as you may have already seen.